# Вывод всех дочерних каталогов(которые хранят в себя некоторые данные) из подкаталога

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-database

В общем, необходимо сделать вывод программу событий на мероприятии.

```
reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Events");
```

Хотел использовать getRoot, getParent но нормального описания я не нашёл. 
Вот структура каталога.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вопрос состоит в том, как мне обратится к каталогу и прочитать значения его подкаталогов.

Answer (score 0):

**Например, вывод данных подкаталога "14-00"**

```
TextView textView;

reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Events").child("20-04-2019").child("14-00");
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

              textView.setText(dataSnapshot.child("Event").getValue().toString() + " , " + dataSnapshot.child("Time").getValue().toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Я и сам примерно такой макет использую, но мне нужно подтягивать все данные из каталога Events. Чтобы все новости на 1 форме были, а не только 14 00.